# represent multiple entities to one entity relationship

Tags: performance, query-performance

If suppose, I have following tables:

[image]

Here, `person` can own either `home` or `car`. `person` can't own both at a time. If `person` owns `home`, then `owns` field will be equal to `1`, if it owns `car`, `owns` field will be equal to `2`.

Then, to retrieve what person owns, I will have to fire two queries in application like this:

```
select first_name, last_name, owns from person where id=1000;

if(owns == 1){
    select id, no_of_rooms, area, city from home where person_id=1000;
}else if(owns == 2){
    select id, make, model, color from car where person_id=1000;
}
```

Also, what I will do, after first query has executed, someone has deleted things for that person. Then I got in zombie state, I had known person information, but now have no idea about thing he owns.

Or may be I can do like this:

[image]

Then query will be:

```
select p.first_name, p.last_name, t.id, t.type_of_thing, t.no_of_rooms, t.area, t.city, t.make, t.model, t.color from person p, owned_thing t where p.id=1000 and p.id = t.person_id;

if(type_of_thing == 1){
    // process home in application
}else if(type_of_thing == 2){
    // process car in application
}
```

Which approach is better? Or is there any other better approach than this? I am going to use MySQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an attribute value to indicate what entity a `person` owns. Instead, take advantage of the relational nature of the database in your queries. Remove the `owns` column from `person` and find related entities by joining the tables:

```
SELECT 
p.id AS person_id, p.first_name, p.last_name,
h.id AS home_id, h.no_of_rooms, h.area, h.city,
c.id AS car_id, c.make, c.model, c.color
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN home h
ON p.id = h.person_id
LEFT JOIN car c
ON p.id c.person_id
WHERE p.id = 1
```

A `LEFT (OUTER) JOIN` will select the desired `person` whether it owns any entities or not. You can then use logic in your application to detect which owned entities have values and which are NULL. Use an `INNER JOIN` to only select the `person` if it also owns one of the entities.